# Internet browsing issue for all network users in different timings

Tags: internet

I have a WatchGuard Firebox that I've recently configured. All of the policies look fine and all appropriate services seem to be working correctly.

However, we are facing browsing issue suddenly during the day for all users, but RDP, Lync and outlook working for all users without any interruption. Here we are using 8 MBPS internet lease line for 60 users. Your suggestion most valuable and great input for us.

Thanks/Kathir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line is low-speed for 60 users.
If only one of them uses P2P with 200+ connections, it can cause exactly what you described.

Does your Firebox equipment support QoS ?
The best solution to this would be to configure QoS to prioritize http traffic (80,8080 +443, etc).

Also, check if there is a number of simultaneous connections limit set in your Firebox. If there is, increase it significantly. 
These toys have enough throughput and general speed to handle enough connections.